# Can I go back to previously visited islands?

Tags: risen-2

Now that [this question is answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64358/is-there-any-use-for-the-small-crystal-cave-on-the-starting-island), I'd like to go back to that cave. I already have  a ship (just set my foot on the third island, after you join the pirates. Can I go back somehow? If so, how, and if I can't do it yet, when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to travel between islands once you become a captain. That happens soon after you deal with Crow on the Sword Coast.

To travel simply talk to your helmsman at the ship's wheel and choose "It's time to set a new course" dialogue option.

Answer (score -1):

**You can fast travel via the start menu:**

[image: fast travel]<sup>[1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3op_6rLPoLM&hd=1&t=1m38s)</sup>

Comment: If I try to go to another location like that, it says "You can't travel there, because you're on another island"